# Will app receipt reflect active subscription before transaction has been completed?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

I'm developing the subscription logic for my application and wondering **whether the app receipt will reflect an automatically renewed subscription before the transaction has been received and marked as completed**?

*Scenario:* subscription has expired, but user has auto-renew turned on. He opens my application, which notices subscription has expired. While waiting for the new transaction to arrive, it checks the latest receipt for the current status. Will the latest in-app purchase receipt (`latest_receipt_info` -> `lastObject`) be for the previous transaction that just expired, or will it be the new updated transaction even though that has not yet been delivered to my application and marked as completed?

Should I treat an expiration date in the past (without `is_in_billing_retry_period` being true) as an expired subscription, or should I wait for any new transactions to tick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I have determined that the *latest receipt* indeed does contain the most recent expiration date, despite this not being delivered to the device and marked as completed.

There was however a small overlap just after the subscription had expired where the receipt was not yet updated with the latest transaction, and as such claimed the subscription had expired despite it automatically renewing. Giving it a few minutes however seemed to do the trick, as it now claimed the subscription was still valid despite the transaction itself not being received by the application.

If anyone can confirm this or provide additional insight, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: It maybe takes time for receipt to be propagated from Apple servers to device. I see this on my backend too. It takes some time there to receive a notification from Apple that contains a new receipt. But pinging Apple servers directly (using old receipt data) should return you the new receipt with all new data.

Also I believe we should disregard `is_in_billing_retry_period` since Apple may attempt to renew a subscription for up to 60 days....